# SharePoint App Development AppWeb communication with HostWeb

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem in a SharePoint-Hosted App. All I want to do is, get the lists of the web, in which the app is running and work with these lists.

With this code I get the lists in the AppWeb:

```
this.web = context.get_web();
this.lists = this.web.get_lists();
this.context.load(this.lists);
```

I already tried something like that, to get the lists from the HostWeb:

```
this.context = new SP.ClientContext("https://sharepoint-server.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/");
var oWebsite = client.get_web();
this.lists = oWebsite.get_lists();
this.context.load(this.lists);
```

But it won't return the lists from this web.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this.context.ExecuteQuery() after your call to the Load method. Objects in the context are not available until after the ExecuteQuery() call.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

After calling the 'load' function you need to call the 'executeQueryAsync' method with a callback function to get the results: See this [example code from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListTasks) :

```
function retrieveAllListProperties(siteUrl) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
  this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
  clientContext.load(collList);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
  var listInfo = '';
  var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

  while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
      listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
}
alert(listInfo); }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); }
```